# How do I increase the number of AWS lamda invocations?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda function which is supposed to forward a messages from CloudWatch to ElasticSearch.
The lambda functions is written in Python (3.6), and is supposed to run every 5 seconds, since I write message to CloudWatch every 5 seconds. 
However, in the monitoring board of this lambda message I see only 9 invocations per minute.
I am trying to figure out why is AWS throttling this down so badly ...

If it is of any help, I setup the timeout of the lambda to 1 minute, and the number of error is 0 per minute for the last 3 hours.

Can anyone give me an advice how to increase the number of invocations per minute?

The lamda is triggered by subscribing a log group from cloudwatch to a lambda function. I chose "stream to AWS lambda"

Comment: How is the Lambda function being triggered exactly?

Comment: I chose streaming ... see my answer above

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee that the Lambda function will be called once for each log event. Each invocation is probably getting more than one log message.

Comment: Oh! You are so right! How come I have not seen this before. Some invocations have more than one messages in them!

Answer (score 1):

A few things to look at:

- How is the lambda function being triggered?
- If it's executed when new cloudwatch logs are loaded, is it possible that a single lambda invocation might have multiple log events in it?  For example, AWS Cloudtrail logs events to S3 and I trigger lambda for new S3 files.  Many of those files have multiple cloudtrail events inside a single log - this may be nothing like what you're doing but just in case...

By default Lambda allows 1000 concurrent executions so I doubt it's something on the Lambda side that's limiting what you're seeing.

[Lambda Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)

[Lambda - Concurrent Executions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html)